# Initialize multiple immutable arrays in one loop

Tags: swift

This is my code:

```
class Birthgiver {}
class Son: Birthgiver {}
class Daughter: Birthgiver {}

class BirthgiverHolder {
    let sons: [Son]
    let daughters: [Daughter]

    init(birthGivers: [Birthgiver]) {
        // How to initializer both sons and daugthers in 1 loop?
        // This is my current way (looping twice):
        sons = birthGivers.compactMap { $0 as? Son }
        daughters = birthGivers.compactMap { $0 as? Daughter }
    }
}
```

I am looping twice over the array `birthGivers`. Is there some way I can **initialize** both sons and daughters **while only looping once** over `birthGivers`? I don't want to mark the arrays as `vars`.

Comment: Unless `birthGivers` has 100s of objects, I wouldn't worry about it. The trivial overhead of looping twice outweighs the more difficult to read code you would need to write to loop once.

Comment: @rmaddy In the real code there are lots of subclasses of `Birthgiver`, so in my case it could benefit a lot (without profiling it, but I am still wondering if there is an answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1: Have local vars and populate your constants when you’re done:

```
init(birthGivers: [Birthgiver]) {
    var sons: [Son] = []
    var daughters: [Daughter] = []

    for child in birthGivers {
        switch child {
            case let son as Son: sons.append(son)
            case let daughter as Daughter: daughters.append(daughter)
            default: break
        }
    }

    self.sons = sons
    self.daughters = daughters
}
```

Option 2: You can achieve it with `reduce(into:)`, too (though I personally find the above more readable):

```
init(birthGivers: [Birthgiver]) {
    (sons, daughters) = birthGivers.reduce(into: ([], [])) {
        switch $1 {
        case let son as Son: $0.0.append(son)
        case let daughter as Daughter: $0.1.append(daughter)
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Option 3: Stick with `compactMap` approach:

```
init(birthGivers: [Birthgiver]) {
    sons = birthGivers.compactMap { $0 as? Son }
    daughters = birthGivers.compactMap { $0 as? Daughter }
}
```

That last option is perfectly adequate in most cases. You’d need an extraordinary number of records for the performance difference to be observable.

Comment: `([], [])` would be sufficient as the  initial result in version #2, the type can be inferred automatically.

Comment: @MartinR - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor that code to loop once but it's far more complicated and harder to read. Unless you have hundreds of objects in the `birthgiver` array, this is probably not worth the effort.

```
class BirthgiverHolder {
    let sons: [Son]
    let daughters: [Daughter]

    init(birthGivers: [Birthgiver]) {
        var sons = [Son]()
        var daughters = [Daughter]()
        for giver in birthGivers {
            if let son = giver as? Son { sons.append(son) }
            else if let daughter = giver as? Daughter { daughters.append(daughter) }
        }

        self.sons = sons
        self.daughters = daughters
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, this isn't likely to make any performance difference. If you really want to try it though, you could do it with `reduce`:

```
(sons, daughters) = birthGivers.reduce(into: ([Son](),[Daughter]())) {arrays, element in
    if let element = element as? Son {
        arrays.0.append(element)
    } else if let element = element as? Daughter {
        arrays.1.append(element)
    }
}
```

Here we create a tuple of two arrays, assign the elements to them as appropriate, and then assign them to your class properties.